# Is it possible to run 2 threads on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading

Hey i am working on a little game that counts how many times u clicked on an image in 30 seconds.
I have 2 separate functions, one function generates a new location to the image and updates the player score, and the other one count down from 30 seconds and updates the "Clicked" paragraph.

The problem is that i can't seem to run 2 functions at the same time I done some research and i saw that js can only run one thread so how is this possible to do?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='ball' src="ball.png" alt="Logo"style="position: absolute; top: 450px; left: 900; width:70px;height:70px;" onclick="moveBall()">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="timer"></p>
    <p id="Clicks" style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size:150px; color:brown;">0</p>
    <script>
        function moveBall()
        {
            var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
            ball.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
            ball.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900)
            document.getElementById('Clicks').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('Clicks').innerHTML) + 1;
            if(document.getElementById('Clicks').innerHTML == 20)
            {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#68a2ff";
                document.getElementById('Clicks').style.color = '#ff688d';
            }
        }
        function sleep() 
        {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var finish = start + 20;
            while(finish - start != 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = finish - start;
            }

        } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look up web workers.

Comment: No, JavaScript is single threaded. However, you can use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: Multiple threads or not, that busy loop is a mistake. That is definitely not what you want to do. *edit* in fact it's worse than a mistake; you never change `finish` or `start` in the loop, so it's basically going to get you that "A script is taking too much time" popup.

Comment: @Poiny i did it because i thought i can simply put it in a thread but now i''m confused..

Comment: Yeah, look up `setTimeout` instead... or `setInterval`, although the former is better here

Comment: You can not use a while loop, it locks up the browser. That innerHTML will never show anything but the last iteration.

Comment: A setInterval would do the trick for you. I am not pretty sure that you are providing the correct solution to your issue. A better way would be to redesign your solution in more convenient approach.

Comment: But what if I want to display how many seconds have left in a text?

Comment: I looked up on setTimeout and setInterval But its not what i'm looking for, these functions execute another function after certain amount of time.. I'm looking for something to call the function until timer is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, try setTimeout. I tested with 30 seconds and it works. It only updates the score during the 30 second mark.

Edit: try making the timer shorter so you don't have to wait 30 seconds. i.e. 3000 instead of 30000. I didn't implement showing the timer.

Edit: I added the timer. It's not perfect but close enough. I changed it to setInterval and time to 10 seconds.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img id='ball' src="ball.png" alt="Logo" style="position: absolute; top: 450px; left: 900; width:70px;height:70px;" onclick="moveBall()">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="timer"></p>
  <p id="Clicks" style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size:150px; color:brown;">0</p>
  <script>
    let isTimesUp = false;
    let isTimerStart = false;
    let timer = 10;
    let score = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
      if (timer >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timer--;
      } else {
        isTimesUp = true;
      }
    }, 1000);

    function moveBall() {
      var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
      ball.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
      ball.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900);
      isTimerStart = true;
      if (!isTimesUp) {
        score++;
        document.getElementById('Clicks').innerHTML = score;
      }

      if (document.getElementById('Clicks').innerHTML == 20) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#68a2ff";
        document.getElementById('Clicks').style.color = '#ff688d';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working btw how can I update the timer in the <p id="timer">?

Comment: @yarinCohen I edited my answer. Change the timer variable to increase or decrease the timer time. Right now it's 10 seconds.